# How do I update records in sql using other records as values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

MS SQL Server 2008 - 
I have a db table where I have a small subset of rows that have a near match, save for 2 columns, elsewhere in the table.  How would you structure a SQL update loop to go through the subset (record1) and search for its matching counterpart (record2) and then copy a value from a column (record2.columnX) to update the other(record1.columnX)?

Before:

```
TxID|RecordID|ColumnA|ColumnX|ColumnY    
1   |111.222 |ggg    |1234   |subset1
2   |111.222 |ggg    |3456   |subset2
3   |111.333 |hhh    |6789   |subset1
4   |111.333 |hhh    |7890   |subset2
5   |111.444 |jjj    |2345   |subset1
5   |111.444 |jjj    |5678   |subset2
```

After:

```
TxID|RecordID|ColumnA|ColumnX|ColumnY    
1   |111.222 |ggg    |1234   |subset1
2   |111.222 |ggg    |1234   |subset2
3   |111.333 |hhh    |6789   |subset1
4   |111.333 |hhh    |6789   |subset2
5   |111.444 |jjj    |2345   |subset1
5   |111.444 |jjj    |2345   |subset2
```

Self-taught, relatively new to SQL.  Patience is appreciated.

Comment: Do you always ant to keep the lowest `ColumnX` value? The first value?

Comment: Not necessarily.  They just need to match.  ColumnX is what links the two records in a downstream system.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an update with inner join on min(TxID)  group by RecordID

```
  update my_table t1
  inner join 
  (
      select RecordID, ColumnA, ColumnX, ColumnY
      from my_table 
      where (TxID, RecordID ) in (
        select min(TxID), RecordID 
      from my_table 
      group by RecordID) 
  ) ttt on ttt.RecordID = t1.RecordID  
  set  t1.ColumnX = ttt.ColumnX
```

Comment: @Jacobm001   sould be kept the ColumnX for min(TxID)  ...  for each reecordID

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
UPDATE table t1 SET columnX=sq.columnXmin
FROM  (
   SELECT t2.RecordID, MIN(t2.columnX) as columnXmin
   FROM   table t2
   GROUP  BY t2.RecordID
   ) AS sq
WHERE  t1.RecordID = sq.RecordID;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Does this assume the data is in two separate tables?

Comment: No, actually you can achieve that with just 1 table, just the aliases are different.

Comment: My apologies, I understand how you structured things now.  This worked exactly as needed.  Thank you.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you found it to be helpful! Can you leave me an upvote? :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
UPDATE  t1
SET     t1.ColumnX = t2.ColumnX
FROM    @table t1
        INNER JOIN @table t2 ON t1.RecordID = t2.RecordID
                                AND t1.ColumnA = t2.ColumnA
                                AND t1.ColumnY <> t2.ColumnY
                                AND t1.TxID > t2.TxID -- the lowest TxID keeps its original value
```

Or...

```
UPDATE  t1
SET     t1.ColumnX = t2.ColumnX
FROM    @table t1
        INNER JOIN @table t2 ON t1.RecordID = t2.RecordID
                                AND t1.ColumnA = t2.ColumnA
                                AND t1.ColumnY <> t2.ColumnY
                                AND t1.TxID < t2.TxID -- the largest TxId keeps its original value
```

Comment: Thank you for providing both solutions.  Does this assume the records are in separate tables (t1 & t2)?  In my instance all of the records are in the same table.

Comment: @mboucher no, it assumes all the records are in 1 table. T1 and T2 are just aliases of the same table but you need both aliases so you can join the table to itself. Hope this is clear. In my example the only table used is called `@table`